# ExtJS: Set loading mask only for Ext.panel.Panel items container

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've got `Ext.panel.Panel` with toolbar (`dockedItems`) and dynamically created content (`items`). I want to `.setLoading()` only for panel items and leave toolbar active. Is there way to select panel items container component?

*P.S. I can use `myPanel.items.each(function(item) {item.setLoading()})`, but its bad solution imo.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always apply the loading mask only to the body of the panel, so the toolbar is active and clickable.

To do this operation is very simple. 
You have to invoke the `.setLoading()` of the panel specifing `setLoading(load, target)` where load is a boolean and the target is the target of the loading mask, that should be something like `target = panel.body`.

According my answer I've made a little fiddle for you:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12h0

The code of the fiddle is:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        border: true,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        margin: 100,
        id: 'myPanel',
        defaults: {
            margin: 10
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            pack: 'middle'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            id: 'input'
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'Other things',
            border: false
        }],
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            items: [{
                text: 'Start Loading',
                listeners: {
                    click: function(th) {
                        Ext.getCmp('input').setValue('opetation');
                        var panel = Ext.getCmp('myPanel');
                        if (!panel.loading) panel.loading = true;
                        else panel.loading = false;
                        panel.setLoading(panel.loading, panel.body);

                        th.setText(panel.loading ? 'Stop Loading' : 'Start Loading');
                    }
                }
            }]
        }]
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Thx for answer, exactly what I was asking. Could you help me abit more? I use `overflowY: 'scroll'` on my panel and sometimes contet is too large so _Loading..._ text is under visible part of panel. How I can display _Loading..._ text at top of my panel body with some indent from toolbar?

Comment: The problem is that the loading panel don't completely cover the panel if you use the scroll bar?

Comment: Nope, loading mask fully cover the panel, but panel content height greater that screen height and `Loading...` text displayed in the middle of panel under screen bottom border.

Comment: you can change the position of the loading message using the property `loadingpanel.msgWrapEl` and change the poistion with several functions, for instance `.setXY()`. Please note that `var loadingpanel = panel.setLoading(.....)`. I hope this help!